# ArcPy how to get field names dynamically from shapefile in customized plugin?

Tags: arcpy, feature-layer

On selection of a feature layer ArcMap tools display all the fields, Zonal Statistics is one of the example. I have entered my feature as fishnet and it has shown me all the fields in a list below.

[image]

I know how to give static drop down list, is there any way to make this list dynamic?

My tool looks like below without dynamic field display

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in the script properties, under the Parameters tab. In the Parameter properties there's a variable called "Obtained from" - you might have to scroll down to see it. Set that to the parameter name of your input layer.